# How to log old/new rows as XML in triggers

Tags: sql, xml, plsql, triggers

I would like to the the old & new rows as XML to an exceptions table when a trigger cannot succeed. I am used to using a generic `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN` clause to log out failures, what I cannot figure out is have to capture (so I can log) the `OLD` and `NEW` pseudorows into XML.

It seems like

```
old_x := dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from OLD');
```

ought to work, but perhaps I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't select from `old`, and there is no way to access the `old` values generically, I'm afraid - you have to specify `old.empno`, `old.ename` etc. one by one.

Tom Kyte has shown how to **generate** triggers to overcome this [here on asktom.oracle.com](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:59412348055).

Comment: never tried select on old/new before, just wanted it for logging. Assuming too much I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Reading [the fine document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955):

> A trigger that fires at row level can access the data in the row that it is processing by using **correlation names**. The default correlation names are OLD, NEW, and PARENT.
>
> OLD, NEW, and PARENT are also called **pseudorecords**, because they have record structure, but are allowed in fewer contexts than records are. The structure of a pseudorecord is table_name%ROWTYPE, where table_name is the name of the table on which the trigger is created (for OLD and NEW) or the name of the parent table (for PARENT).

(Pseudorecords have also other restrictions explicitly mentioned in the documentation but not quoted here.)

Among all the other things the restrictions mean one can't use pseudorecords e.g. in [insert statement extension](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/insert_statement.htm#LNPLS99950).

So very much the only thing you can do with a pseudorecord is to refer it's fields one-by-one.

**Example**

```
create table a (a number, b date);
create table b (a number, b date);

create or replace trigger a_trg 
before insert on a
for each row
begin
  -- NEW pseudorecord is not a real record and therefore compilation will fail:
  -- PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW'
  -- insert into b values :new;

  -- NEW pseudorecord fields have to be referenced one-by-one
  insert into b(a, b) values(:new.a, :new.b);
end;
/
show errors

insert into a values(1, sysdate);

select * from a;
select * from b;
```

Comment: @user272736 - I admit to duplicity, I was pretty sure this was not possible when I wrote the question, but was certainly willing to be surprised -- figured I was not the only person. I'm not sure RTFM applies when the FM obscures the answer, e.g, I am not 100% sure what the restriction "A pseudorecord cannot appear in a **Record-Level Operation.**" really means as a **RLO** is never carefully defined in oracle or the database world. Thank you.